# Права доступа к дискам Linux

Tags: linux

Проблема в доступе к дискам ntfs. Kubuntu 18.04 LTS

Вывод ls -l

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 krozn krozn 4096 дек 12 15:01 Fallout
drwxrwxrwx 1 krozn krozn 4096 дек  8 18:50 Repository
```

Оба диска должны быть с полностью открытыми правами для текущего пользователя. 
В Fallout работает touch и mkdir. Тут все как надо.
Repository только чтение. Не могу создать даже файл.

В чем может быть проблема? Посоветуйте пожалуйста как исправить.

Пробовал sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb4
Пробовал давать права отдельным папкам.
Пробовал через root.

Comment: Попробуйте это: [ntfs-3g](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо de_frag помогло.

1. umount диск
2. sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sdb4 /media/krozn/Repository
3. У меня вывел вот такое

   ```
   The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
   Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
   Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
   unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
   or fast restarting.)
   ```
4. Заходим в win. Я покопался на диске потом reboot
5. Все работает